Creating a React library with Vite and Lingui
I'm trying to create a React library with Lingui using Vite.
For simplicity let's say I have a Welcome component:
import { Trans } from "@lingui/macro";

function Welcome() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Trans context="Library">Library welcome</Trans>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Welcome;

The library also provides an I18nApp:
function I18nApp({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    dynamicActivate("en");
  }, []);

  return <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>{children}</I18nProvider>;
}

And dynamicActivate:
import { i18n } from "@lingui/core";

async function dynamicActivate(locale: string) {
  //somehow either as strings or loaded files it will get the app's .po files, but its currently empty
  const mergedPaths: string[] = [];

  const { message: libraryTranslation } = await import(`./assets/locales/${locale}.po`);
  let mergedMessages = libraryTranslation || {};

  for (const translationPath of mergedPaths) {
    const { messages } = await import(`${translationPath}/locales/${locale}.po`);
    mergedMessages = { ...mergedMessages, ...messages };
  }

  i18n.load(locale, mergedMessages);
  i18n.activate(locale);
}

export default dynamicActivate;

And I have an app welcome as well:
import { Trans } from "@lingui/macro";

function Welcome() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Trans context="App">App welcome</Trans>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Welcome;

How can I bundle the library with it's corresponding .po translation files (the files are in src/assets/locales)? I believe if I can do that, I can provide the app's .po files in one way or the other to dynamicActivate and that should be rather straight forward. What setting should I turn on in lingui.config.ts or vite.config.ts? Or what documentation can I follow?
